# Power of an infinitesimal generator of a $C_0$-semigroup in a Banach space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators, unbounded-operators

Let $A$ be the infinitesimal generator of a $C_0$-semigroup of linear operators in a Banach space. Let $n$ be a positive integer, $n\geq2$. Is $A^n$ closed?

Here (setting $A^1$ $:=$ $A$,   and denoting the domain of $A$ by $\cal{D}(A)$), the operator $A^n$ has been defined inductively for  $n=2,3...,$, by
$$
{\cal{D}}(A^n):=\{f: f\in {\cal{D}}(A^{n-1})\; \text{and} \; A^{n-1}f \in {\cal{D}}(A) \},
$$ 
$$
A^{n}f:=A (A^{n-1} f).
$$

Comment: Cross-posted from [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3137197).

Comment: This is more an exercise and there are many arguments. For example you could show that the resolvent set of $A^n$ is not empty.

Comment: @AndrásBatkai: This was my first thought, too; but after all, I think it's a bit more subtle: the resolvent set of $A^n$ can indeed by empty (for instance, if the spectrum of $A$ is the left halfplane). So with this argument you can only show that $(A-\lambda)^n$ is closed for some scalar $\lambda$ - but then it is not obvious why this should imply that $A^n$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more general result:

**Theorem.** Let $A$ be a closed linear operator with non-empty resolvent set on a complex Banach space. Then $p(A)$ is a closed operator for every complex polynomial $p$.

*Reference:* Markus Haase, *The Functional Calculus for Sectorial Operators* (2006), Proposition A.6.2.